# setAttribute('display','block') not working selenium-webdriver node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
ele = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//*[@class='classname']"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:block')", ele);
```

The above code isn't working. I am unable to set the style for display. However, below code doesn't have any issue.

```
ele = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//*[@class='classname']"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','top: 0px;')", ele);
```

My CSS is something like this:

```
element.style {
    display: block;
}
```

What's the different here and how do I set the display from 'none' to 'block' using selenium-webdriver?

Comment: why would you use attribute to set style?

Comment: Whats the other way?

Comment: `.style.display = "block"`

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the code.

Answer (score 1):

you are using this 'display:block' but forget about semicolon please add ; like below code.

driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:block;')", ele);